# Form styles missing in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a new angular 15 app using angular material. I implemented a form field like on this page: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples. If you enter a wrong value in the email field you can see a error message. This message has the class `mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper` and as you can see in the screenshot some styles are applied e.g for font size:

[image]

In my app there are also some style rules for this class, but the font-size is missing.

```
mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I'm wondering if these additional styles are only for the examples but I don't think so because in my app the error text is too large.

Comment: See that the styles is in a global styles. If you want to "override" you need put your style in "styles.css" or "styles.sccs" (really you can put in any place where you indicate in your angular.json under projects-->your-app-->architect-->build-->options-->styles

Answer (score 0):

If the font is to large can you just add font-size: 13px;

Comment: Sure, but I want to know why the style info is missing because it could be that also other styles are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You must override class of material, like:

```
    /deep/ .mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```